# MapReduce on Cassandra

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra

I am working on a simple MapReduce program to read data from a Cassandra column family but ran into following errors. Any hints on how to proceed is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
Cassandra version : 1.0.3
Hadoop version : 0.20.2
HADOOP_CLASSPATH has: apache-cassandra-1.0.3.jar, libthrift-0.6.jar, commons-lang-2.4.jar and guava-10.0.1.jar
What works : Hadoop MR word count example, Reads from Cassandra column family using cassandra-cli, Thrift and Hector
```

Error:

```
11/12/01 20:05:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201112010835_0009<br/>
11/12/01 20:05:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%<br/>
11/12/01 20:05:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201112010835_0009_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED<br/>
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.common.collect.AbstractIterator<br/>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)<br/>
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)<br/>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)<br/>
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)<br/>
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)<br/>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)<br/>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)<br/>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)<br/>
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)<br/>
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)<br/>
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)<br/>
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)<br/>
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.ColumnFamilyRecordReader.initialize(ColumnFamilyRecordReader.java:158)<br/>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:418)<br/>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:620)<br/>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)<br/>
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)<br/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you adding the cassandra libraries to the classpath for all of your task trackers? From the wiki page http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport:

```
One configuration note on getting the task trackers to be able to perform queries over
Cassandra: you'll want to update your HADOOP_CLASSPATH in your <hadoop>/conf/hadoop-env.sh 
to include the Cassandra lib libraries. For example you'll want to do something like 
this in the hadoop-env.sh on each of your task trackers:


export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=/opt/cassandra/lib/*:$HADOOP_CLASSPATH
```

The path in that example should obviously be replaced with the correct path to the cassandra libraries on your system.

Comment: Yes, I have the classpath set to cassandra lib on a single node cluster. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of cassandra? Did you restart the task tracker after you modified the classpath?

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to make sure that version of all the Cassandra jars (all jars you find in lib directory of cassandra binary installtion) you are using for the Hadoop are compatible with Hadoop version.

2) Also Cassandra jars may have some dependencies and you should have the correct version of this dependency jars.

3) I ran into the same issue because of such version mismatch of the jars.Resolved it after cleaning all Cassandra jars from hadoop classpath and then adding all the jars from latest version of Cassandra.